# MPD fails to load music

Tags: linux, mpd

I installed MPD on my raspberry running pidora.

I compiled it myself, so there might be a problem with that.

I configured mpd as it is written in the normal wiki pages:

Here is my .mpdconf

```
music_directory "/var/lib/mpd/music"
playlist_directory "/var/lib/mpd/playlists"
db_file "~/.mpd/database"
user "mpd"
group "audio"
bind_to_address "10.0.0.200"
port "6600"
auto_update "yes"
audio_output {
 type "alsa"
 name "My ALSA Device"
 device "hw:0,0" # optional
}
```

I opened the stream with GMPC and it shows songs in the database. Buf $ mpc stats returns 0 songs.

If I want to add a song per mpc with

```
MPD_HOST=10.0.0.200 mpc --verbose --wait load o\'brother/Disillusion/Parasitical.ogg
```

it only prints

```
client: [5] opened from 10.0.0.200:37865
client: [5] process command list
client: process command "load "o'brother/Disillusion/Parasitical.ogg""
playlist: No such playlist
client: command returned 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You tried to add the file as playlist, this doesn't work as it's not one.
To play a file in mpc, you have to add it to a virtual playlist, then play this one with play.

```
mpc add "file"
mpc play
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem, and it's **probably because you don't have the required file type support compiled-in**.

Things to check:

- Ensure the file type (e.g. flac, mp3) is supported by your build.  You can see what is an isn't enabled at the end of the output when you run `./configure`.  For example:

```
    ...
    ########### MPD CONFIGURATION ############

    Archive support:
        (+bzip2) (-ISO9660) (-ZIP) 
    Client support:
        (+IPv6) (+TCP) (+UNIX Domain Sockets) 
    Storage support:
        (-NFS) (-SMB) 
    File format support:
        (-AAC) (-AdPlug) (+DSD) (-C64 SID) (-FFMPEG) (+FLAC) (-FluidSynth) (-GME) 
        (-libsndfile) (-MikMod) (-MODPLUG) (-MAD) (-MPG123) (-Musepack) 
        (-Opus) (-OggTremor) (+OggVorbis) (-WAVE) (-WavPack) (-WildMidi) 
    ...
```

This example shows `+FLAC` and `+OggVorbis` so .flac and .ogg files are supported, but doesn't support mp3s (would show `+MPG123` instead of `-MPG123`).  You'll need to install extra packages or libraries to get additional support, and then to re-run `./configure` and check the output again.  *On CentOS I needed to install the `flac-devel` package to get flac files to be supported before I built mpd.*
**I also needed the `libvorbis-devel` package on CentOS 7 to get Ogg Vorbis support to work**.

- Ensure your `~/mpdconf` or `/etc/mpd.conf` file points the `music_directory` at where your music files can be found
- Run `mpc update` to add all music files to your music database
- Try running `mpd --no-daemon --stderr --verbose` to get a load of debug info whilst the daemon is running.  If you run `mpc update` as above for the first time and it doesn't print info about files being added then it's probably not got support for the file type compiled in

You might get similar effects if you don't have ID3 or other tag information support, but I'd expect the filenames to show up and music to be playable, just not the titles and artists etc from the tags.

Hope this helps!